# Use the target name in a target-specific variable

Tags: makefile

Can I use the target name in a target-specific variable?

```
program_%: CFILE=path/program_%/do_it.c
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
                       This does not work
```

So that when doing "make program_xyz", the CFILE will be "path/program_xyz/do_it.c".

Comment: I think you need [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to use `CFILE` for.  Since you gave us no details about that I'll just answer your exact question: sure, you can do that:

```
program_% : CFILE = path/program_$*/do_it.c

program_% : ; @echo $(CFILE)

$ make program_foo
path/program_foo/do_it.c
```

However, my suspicion is you wanted to do more with `CFILE` besides simply use it inside this recipe.  If so, the above solution my not work for what you really want to do...